# Android use WindowManager showing a floating view, click outside disappear and the event can be transmited

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

Android use WindowManager encounter a problem, a floating view, above an Activity. The floating view and the Activity are in two different application, so the Activity can't be altered.

How to achieve this effect:

Click on the screen outside of float view, floating view  disappear, and the click event will be passed to the Activity, such as the blanks just had a button, point down the button, the float view disappear, and the button is clickable, or an Edittext, click after the floating view disappear, Edittext can be input.

Please give me an idea how to make a listen or intercept the event. or give me another way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

First define id for your rootview of view you are using.

```
private final String TAG = "MOVING POPUP"; 
private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF;
private View mView;
private boolean isViewVisible = false;
private WindowManager windowManager;

private long pressStartTime;
private float pressedX;
private float pressedY;
private boolean stayedWithinClickDistance;
/**
 * Max allowed duration for a "click", in milliseconds.
 */
private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 1000;

/**
 * Max allowed distance to move during a "click", in DP.
 */
private static final int MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE = 15;

private void createView() 
{
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_book_text_selection_main, null, false);
    View mdismiss = mView.findViewById(R.id.btnApply);
    View llRoot = mView.findViewById(R.id.llRoot);
    try 
    {
        mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                removeView();
            }
        });

        mdismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                removeView();
            }
        });

        llRoot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                        pressStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        pressedX = event.getX();
                        pressedY = event.getY();
                        stayedWithinClickDistance = true;

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        long pressDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressStartTime;
                        if (pressDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION && stayedWithinClickDistance) 
{
perform your on click event here
                           }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        if (stayedWithinClickDistance && distance(pressedX, pressedY, event.getX(), event.getY()) > MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE) {
                            stayedWithinClickDistance = false;
                        }

                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, paramsF);

                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "ON TOUCH ERROR--->" + e.getMessage());
    }

    setViewPosition();
    addView();
}

private float distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    float dx = x1 - x2;
    float dy = y1 - y2;
    float distanceInPx = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return pxToDp(distanceInPx);
}

private float pxToDp(float px) {
    return px / activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}

private void addView() 
{
    if (mView != null && !isViewVisible) 
    {
        isViewVisible = true;
        setViewPosition();
        windowManager.addView(mView, params);
    }
}

private void removeView()
{
    try {
        if (mView != null && isViewVisible)
        {
            windowManager.removeView(mView);
            isViewVisible = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setViewPosition() 
{
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;

    paramsF = params;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        if (isViewVisible)
        {
            removeView();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```